# Cannot run compiled files on file exchange partition on a MBP 3,1

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, compiling

Since I dual boot on my Macbook Pro I created a partition to exchange files between Ubuntu and Mac OS X easily.

I can *copy and delete files easily on the exchange partition from both OS*. I can also compile files from either partition.

**But I cannot run files from Ubuntu!?**
This is the output in the terminal:

```
bash: ./P1c: Keine Berechtigung
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, well. I found a solution:

**I reformatted the partition in MAC to HFS+ and disabled Journaling.**
A bonus effect includes: Time Machine will also backup this partition!

Maybe I should have mentioned that the exchange partition was formatted FAT32.
I think the problem with FAT32 is that it cannot handle permissions so well.

Answer (score 0):

Does the file have execute permission? You can set this with `chmod +x P1c`

Comment: Did not help :(. The permisions are: `-rw-r--r--`

Comment: You'll need rwx user permission, you've only got rw-

Comment: How do I change it? I've tried your code before. With and without sudo, but still not difference. (Sorry, I'm a noob at this...)